# How to diagnose cause of laundry lint

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine, laundry

We inherited a [Fridgidaire washer/drier](https://www.frigidaire.com/Washers-Dryers/Laundry-Center/Laundry-Centers/FFLE3911QW/) (model A02591501A (1408)), and have been trying to figure out why the washer is leaving so much lint on clothes, concentrated in the creases. Here is an example after a wash:

[image]

The dryer removes a lot of the lint left by the washer, but not all. And I can't put all our clothes in the dryer, so I need to figure out how to get the washer to stop leaving so much lint.

Some online resources have suggested this might be detergent residue. I don't think that's the case - I've tried borax, less detergent, smaller loads, and higher rinse level. Nothing changes.

I couldn't find any information about cleaning the drum/tub other than wiping down exposed surfaces, and there's no visible lint trap or mention of one in the manual (for the washer, that is - the dryer has a lint trap, but that doesn't solve my problem). What can I try?

Comment: It sounds like not enough water per my wife, she knows way more about this stuff then I do.

Comment: Yes, some washers have an adjustment for water height. Did that get unexpectedly moved?

Comment: @Gil, we've tried smaller loads and max water ('High' instead of 'Auto'), no difference. More water may still be the answer, but not something I can adjust further.

Comment: Try a load without soap or very little and no other additives to the wash.

Comment: This is not lint.  Lint is specifically fibres knocked off the fabric when washing.

Comment: The last Fridgidaire product I bought was so horrible, I refused payment.  Then I investigated to see if there was a way to profit from what I consider a certain future bankruptcy of such an inept company.  Nope, they are owned by Electrolux.

Comment: For a second I read *"Madrigal Electromotive"* instead of Electrolux there... If so, that would mean their business doesn't need to rely on quality because of *other* revenue streams :)

Comment: if nothing else has helped, i suspect an issue with drain. this looks more like gunk than lint, as in gunk from the last wash's dirty water that has dried into a sludge. try running an empty load, max temp and volume, maybe with a splash of liquid plumber or a targeted washer product, then try a normal load again and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I concur with Gil above.  This looks like soap or detergent residue rather than lint.  try running a load without soap or use liquid soap.  if you have softened water,  you can get away using much less soap too.

Comment: That's a great point. We have softened water and use less than half detergent than what would be considered typical.

Comment: We have tried borax as an additive before, and it didn't help. Would that eliminate this hypothesis?

Comment: I don’t think it would, have you tried liquid detergent and using only 1/3 the ‘normal’ to account for your soft water?

Answer (score 1):

From here it looks like residue from too much fabric softener. Try re-washing the clothes with detergent but no fabric softener. If the residue decreases but does not disappear entirely, you may have to wash several more times to completely remove it.

Comment: We don't use fabric softener.

Comment: @Evan In that case it's definitely NOT fabric softener! By any chance do you have hard water, no water softener, and you're using laundry soap instead of detergent for health or environmental reasons? If so, the residue could be soap scum, which is formed by an exchange between calcium / magnesium in the water and the sodium or potassium ion in the soap. To eliminate soap scum, soften the water or use a non-soap detergent instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is some sort of residue, not lint.  I would remove the detergent draw and clean it (they rapidly become disgusting IME), and then put a washing machine cleaner through the machine.